# tshark capture only dns or http traffic with specific ip adress and write to file

Tags: networking, wireshark, tshark

Hello I want to capture from a specific ip adress dns or http or http2 traffic and save it to a file.
I tried this:

```
tshark -i xxx -w capture-output.pcap -T fields -e ip.src -Y "ip.src == 192.168.178.xxx and (dns or http or http2)"
```

I get this error:
tshark: Display filters aren't supported when capturing and saving the captured packets.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error gives you as much information as you need - you can't use a display filter when saving a packet capture. You have two options here:

### Option 1: Save the capture and use a display filter afterwards

This would look something like

```sh
# Write the initial file with incoming packets
$ tshark -i xxx -w capture-output.pcap
# Filter out the traffic we don't want
$ tshark -r capture-output.pcap -w filtered-output.pcap \
    -T fields -e ip.src -Y "ip.src == 192.168.178.xxx and (dns or http or http2)"
```

### Option 2: Use a capture filter

Use a [capture filter](https://tshark.dev/capture/capture_filters/) instead. Capture filters use a [special syntax](https://biot.com/capstats/bpf.html) that is different from display filters.

The equivalent capture filter you would want to use give your display filter is

`$ tshark -w filtered.pcap -f "src net 192.168.178.0/24 and (udp port 53 or tcp port 80 or tcp port 443)"`

Comment: thx that helped me a lot but I dont know how filter dns or http or http2 traffic. tshark seems to be poor documented or I dont find the right source for capture filters. I looked here: https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters

Comment: So dns is udp port 53 and http is tcp port 80 and http is tcp port 443. You can filter protocols in capture filters by their layer 4 ports.